# PHP __FILE__ inheritence

Tags: php, inheritance

I am trying to write a method that I can use in extended classes that uses the file's full path.  However, when I use `__FILE__` I only get back the path for the class the inherited method is defined in.  Here is an example:

foo.php

```
class foo 
{

    public function getFullFile()
    {
        return __FILE__;
    }
}
```

bar.php

```
class bar extends foo 
{
    public function getFile()
    {
        return __FILE__;
    }

}
```

example.php

```
$foo = new foo();
echo $foo->getFullFile() . PHP_EOL;

$bar = new bar();
echo $bar->getFullFile() . PHP_EOL;
echo $bar->getFile() . PHP_EOL;
```

The output of running example.php:

```
/my/full/path/foo.php
/my/full/path/foo.php
/my/full/path/bar.php
```

Is this expected behavior?  Is there a better way to accomplish this? Am I doing something insanely stupid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not refer to `__FILE__` (for [said reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985774/php-file-inheritence/6985858#6985858)), but you can refer to the file the current object's class has been defined in:

```
class foo 
{
    public function getFullFile()
    {
        $c = new ReflectionClass($this);
        return $c->getFileName();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution compared to the rest as you can call getFullFile() in parent class to get the base filename during runtime.  The other solutions require that you call getFullFile() in the base class only.

Answer (score 2):

`__FILE__` is always the file where the constant is referred to. It's for debugging purposes to you can easily refer back to the exact file where the code that uses `__FILE__` is located. It would be useless to say that it was in 'bar.php', when the definition resides in 'foo.php'.

Answer (score 2):

Some code says more than thousand words...

B.php

```
<?
class B {
  public function bar() {
    return __FILE__;
  }
}
```

A.php

```
<?
require "B.php";
class A extends B {
  public function foo() {
    echo parent::bar();
  }
}
$a = new A();
$a->foo();
```

joe@joe-desktop:~$ php A.php

```
/home/joe/B.php
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want `$bar->getFullFile()` to return bar.php, you'll have to add the function to bar.php.

```
public function getFullFile() {
  return parent::getFullFile();
}
```

Comment: No, I should be able to call bar::getFullFile() without anything special, since I'm extending the foo class.  Also, bar is a class not a method.

Comment: Meant to use the method name instead of bar, either way, you'll have to define it in bar IF you want `__FILE__` to return bar.php

Answer (score 1):

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php for more information on these 'magical constants'. If I am not mistaken these magical constants are a sort of macros and are determined at compile time, not runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour `__FILE__` will always evaluate to the filename of file in which interpreter finds it. Same with other magic constants (`__METHOD__`,  `__CLASS__`, `__LINE__` etc)
As far as I can tell, it is impossible to do waht you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `debug_backtrace()` PHP function. Example of use (my library function my_die is placed in some included php file, but reports the callers location!):

```
function my_die($msg)
{
    $bt = debug_backtrace();

    $file = $bt[0]["file"];
    $line = $bt[0]["line"];
    $func = $bt[1]["function"];

    # session info also!!!
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];

    error_log('Died in ' . $file . ': ' . $line . ': function ' . $func .
            "(): user='{$user}': ip='{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}': " . $msg .
            " (browser: '{$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']})'");
    die($msg);
}
```